# How to delay blits being iterated from a list

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a typewriter effect for text being blitted. By typewriter effect, I simply mean that Im trying to avoid the entirety of the text being blitted on screen at once. Instead, im trying to have each letter appear individually, with a slight delay before the next character in the string appears.

The catch is that im not using pygame's font.render. Instead, i've made my own custom fonts, each letter being saved as a separate image file. Now each alphanumeric character has it's own variable to which it's image is attached and each is appended to a list.

e.g:

```
    letter_IMGs = []
    a = "a" == pygame.image.load("IMG/letter_a.gif)
    letter_IMG.append(a)
```

Lower, I have something along these lines:

```
    letter_pos_x = 0
    text = "Hello"
    for i, c in enumerate(text):
        screen.blit(letter_IMGs[i], (letter_pos_x,0))
        letter_pos_x += 20
        scroll_wait  #this is a clock.delay variable. It's value was set                      outside the loop. I'm just calling it here.
```

Now as you'd guess, the result with that code is that the entire line of text appears simultaneously after the delay. I've been trying to code it as needed from there, but most of what I come up with returns with a "cannot iterate through surface objects" error.

I'm pretty much at a loss on how I should proceed next. Note that, ive been learning a bit of code on my own, on and off, for the past year and that I don't really know what im doing yet. Any and all help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by this? `scroll_wait = 800 #this is a clock.delay variable`

Comment: it's a variable for the pygame.time.delay() method. It's not serving the intended purpose I had for it , but I have it on there because im trying to find a way to delay the blit iteration. 

Using a "hello" string, im hoping to achieve : "h"is blitted, next character in the string is delayed, "e" is blitted, next character in the string is delayed....and so on.

Comment: Shouldn't you call `pygame.time.delay()` instead of just updating a variable?

Comment: Checking over my code, I set the value for the delay outside the main program loop. I just called scroll_wait under that for loop. I'll edit that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without getting into the pygame specifices too much, you just need to change the iterator so it returns substrings rather than letters:

```
def iterate_text(text):
    for r in range(len(text)):
        yield text[:r + 1]
```

which will return the substring iteratively:

```
for t in iterate_text('hello'):
    print t

# h
# he
# hel
# hell
# hello
```

use a separate function to draw the string:

```
def draw_text(x, y, text):
    characters = [letter_IMGs[t] for t in text]
    cursor = x
    for char in characters:
        screen.blit(char, cursor, y)
        cursor += 20
```

in your main loop you can decide when to get the next character.  You'll basically do something like:

```
 typewriter = iter_text('hello world')
 text_to_draw = None     
 advance_text = False
```

at a level outside the loop that survive from frame to frame.  When you want to draw the next character, you set advance_text to True, in and in the main loop:

```
 if typewriter and advance_text:
      text_to_draw = typewriter.next()
      advance_text = False # until you set it again

 if text_to_draw :
     draw_text(0,0, draw_text)
```

You can start over by resetting the typewriter with new text, and control the timing of the new character appearing by setting advance_text to True before the next frame

Comment: First i've heard of the "yield" keyword. But, a quick google search later and I now  know, but surely, only loosely understand, the difference between Iterators and generators. 

You've given me a bunch to get familiar with. Thanks for your time and your help!

Comment: iterator: give you back things one at a time
generator: creates an iterator but controls it (you can, for example, send a signal to the generator and change what it gives back on 'next')

Comment: Why do you need the iterate_text() function? Why can't you more simply use: 
for t in range(len("hello")):
    print "hello"[:t]

Comment: You want to keep it separate so you can change the text :)   And more importanly, the function returns a generator object which can be updated in later frames - or thrown away and replaced if the text changes.  A function in line won't let you pause the execution until a later frame. And as you can see the generator does not advance every frame -- it only advances when advance_text is set